# display all variables for a specific type

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I want to create a menu in `WriteFoodMenu` that lets the user display all available options (which is currently what the `WriteLn` does in `WriteFoodMenu` or only display the options in which the selected venue is located.

So for example if the user selects 'Bakery',

```
WriteLn(mfood.foodtype, ' - ', mfood.chef, ' - ', mfood.venue);
```

will only display options in which the venue is a bakery.

Edit: let me know if i need to include anything else

```
type 
Venues =(cafe, resteraunt, bakery, milkbar, fastfood);

Mfood = record
foodtype, chef: string
venue: Venues;
end;


function FoodType(prompt: String): Venues;
    var
        selection: Integer;
    begin
        WriteLn('Venues:');
        WriteLn('  1. Cafe');
        WriteLn('  2. Restaurant');
        WriteLn('  3. Bakery');
        WriteLn('  4. Milkbar');
        WriteLn('  5. FastFood');

        selection := ReadIntegerRange('Select a venue (1 - 5): ', 1, 5);
        result := Venues(selection - 1);
    end;

    procedure WriteFoodMenu(MFood: MFood);
    begin
    WriteLn(mfood.foodtype, ' - ', mfood.chef, ' - ', mfood.venue);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to select on `Venues`:

```
procedure WriteFoodMenu(Venue: Venues; MFood: MFood);
begin
  if MFood.venue = Venue then
    WriteLn(mfood.foodtype, ' - ', mfood.chef, ' - ', mfood.venue);
end;
```

That only works if you pass the desired venue to the procedure. Now you can have a list of MFoods:

```
const
  Foods: array[0..numOfFoods - 1] of MFood =
  (
    (FoodType: 'Spaghetti'; Chef: 'Luigi'; Venue: resteraunt),
    ( etc...),
    // etc...
    ( etc...)
  );

...
  Venue := FoodType('Select a venue');
  for I := Low(Foods) to High(Foods) do
    WriteFoodMenu(Venue, Foods[I]);
```

Note that it would make sense to display the prompt you pass to `FoodType` before you present the menu. You are currently not using the prompt at all.

Comment: FWIW, the word is *restaurant*, not *resteraunt*.